# Can I extend temporary green card post divorce?

Tags: immigration

I came to the U.S. with a K1 visa. I married my husband in good faith (true love), and I got a temporary 2 year green card in October 2020. It will expire in October 2022. In January 2021, I gave birth to our baby girl. In May 2021, we decided to divorce. We are still in good relationship, we just don’t match. Our baby girl stays with my ex husband (he has 100% custody). I visit her at any time (we divorced but stayed friends).

---

Questions:

1. I want to go back to my country to visit my family (8-9 months tops), then I want to come back and live in the U.S., to be close to my baby girl. I want to be a U.S. citizen eventually, but really need a break to see my family right now. Can I use my temporary Green Card to do this? Will my temporary Green Card allow me to re-enter the U.S. even after the divorce? It will expire only in 2022, so may I use it to travel back to the U.S.?
2. Can I extend this temporary Green Card as it approaches it’s expiration date of October 2022? Or do I have to initiate it’s extension immediately after the divorce?

Comment: You should seek the advice of an immigration attorney. You really should do this as you do not want to abandon your permanent residency. By traveling for such a long time after divorcing and also on a temporary green card status you seem to be abandoning your intention to live in the United States and as such you really should talk to an attorney about this. This is not legal advice (or any advice aside from telling you to consult an attorney knowledgeable in immigration law).

Comment: This asks two different questions, and would be better focused by asking one at a time, ideally about a hypothetical person and not advice for you.  If you want advice for your specific situation, I'd second the advice that you should **really** contact an immigration attorney, as immigration is complicated and often fact-specific and they can advise you better than random people on the internet who probably aren't even lawyers (I'm not, for instance).

Comment: I can not emphasize enough that you should speak to an attorney to get advice on your specific situation before leaving the country.  You have a conditional green card, and 90 days before it expires you and your ex-spouse need to file jointly to remove the conditions on it. You can not renew a conditional green card; you can only petition to change it to a non-conditional green card.